# Download link/button in Wordpress PODS Framework

Tags: wordpress

I want to allow my journal website visitor to download PDF copy of articles.
I am using PODS to display the content on the website. Everything is okay. However, I tried all I could but in vain.

```
<a href="{@permalink}">{@title}</a>
```